# Problems with file I/O in C

Tags: c, file-io, printf

I'm sorry for my bad english, but I'll try to explain my problem.
Using C, i want to make an output of a list of IP addresses.

But, when I open the .txt file, it looks blank. I tried printing on stderr too, but I have no output at all. What's the problem? It seems that `for` loops are not being executed.

Here's the code.
(Would print addresses from 192.168.51.1 to 192.168.51.254)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define B1_S 192
#define B1_E 192
#define B2_S 168
#define B2_E 168
#define B3_S 51
#define B3_E 51
#define B4_S 1
#define B4_E 254
#define FNAME "ip.txt"
#define MIN_RANGE 0
#define MAX_RANGE 255

void to_next(int *x);

main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  int i, j, k, l;
  if(fp = fopen(FNAME, "w"))
  {
    for(i=B1_S; i<=B1_E; to_next(&i))
      for(j=B2_S; j<=B2_E; to_next(&j))
        for(k=B3_S; j<=B3_E; to_next(&k))
          for(l=B4_S; l<=B4_E; to_next(&l))
            fprintf(fp, "%d.%d.%d.%d\n", i,j,k,l);
    fclose(fp);
  }
  else
    printf("Error opening file.\n");
}

void to_next(int *x)
{
  if(*x < MAX_RANGE)
    *x+=1;
  else
    *x = MIN_RANGE;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Typo?

```
         for(k=B3_S; j<=B3_E; to_next(&k))
```

You have a `j` where a `k` should be.

Comment: @user533780: It's a good idea to accept an answer that solves your problem. It's polite and also stops other people wasting time reviewing questions that already have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way your to_next() function is written, your for loops will never terminate if any of the end variables is set to 255.

However, because the end values are always set to something smaller you don't need the to_next function.  I recommend changing to the more normal:

```
for(i=B1_S; i<=B1_E; ++i)
```